# Array with index "" after a database retrieval

Tags: php, arrays

I am practising PHP, trying to learn the ins and outs. Doing so, I am working on a little webshop. One ff the features is the retrieval of the shoppingcart after logging in. This works, but somehow there turns up an item with the index "" in the array orders. I have no clue how it gets there, or how to (if I can't prevent this from happening) remove it from the array... I tried unsetting it, but that has no effect. This is the code that creates the $_SESSION['Bestellen'] array:

```
        $query = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id'];
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            foreach($row as $key => $value){ 
                $order[$key] = $value;                  

                $_SESSION['Bestellen'][$order['product_id']]['aantal'] = $order['ammount'];
                $_SESSION['Bestellen'][$order['product_id']]['product_id'] = $order['product_id'];
            }                       

            $query = "SELECT product_name, price FROM products WHERE product_id = ".$order['product_id'];
            $result2 = mysqli_query($db, $query);
            while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
                foreach($row2 as $key2 => $value2){
                    $item[$key2] = $value2;

                    $_SESSION['Bestellen'][$order['product_id']]['product_name'] = $item['product_name'];
                    $_SESSION['Bestellen'][$order['product_id']]['price'] = $item['price'];

                }
            }
        }
```

I have two items ordered in the database, but the array ends up having a third item (first in the array), without any values, and indexed as "":

```
array(3) {
  [""]=>
  array(2) {
    ["aantal"]=>
    NULL
    ["product_id"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["aantal"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["product_name"]=>
    string(6) "boutje"
    ["price"]=>
    string(4) "0.32"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["aantal"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["product_name"]=>
    string(7) "schroef"
    ["price"]=>
    string(4) "0.15"
  }
}
```

How did it get there? And how do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `$order['product_id']` is missing or empty. Check your database to make sure the row `product_id` exists and is not empty.

....
It could just be that it doesn't exist *yet*..

```
        foreach($row as $key => $value){ 
            $order[$key] = $value;                  
        }
        $_SESSION['Bestellen'][$order['product_id']]['aantal'] = $order['ammount'];
        $_SESSION['Bestellen'][$order['product_id']]['product_id'] = $order['product_id'];
```

Loop through the results and set the $order array before trying to use the variables in your session.

Also, make sure you initialize the $order array first or you could get an unset variable notice..

```
$order = []; //somewhere above your loop
```

Comment: Ofcourse! That explains! I just had to pull it out of the foreach loop. That did the trick. Thank you!